# Is hardcoding a default nopic image in my MvcHelperExtension bad design

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-mvc-helpers

I've just written an MVC helper method to write `img` tags for me, in the method I'm hardcoding a `nopic` image that should be used when no image path is passed in. I **don't** like the hardcoding but don't know what the best approach I could use (given this is MVC and this is a helper) to achieve it would be.

```
public static MvcHtmlString Image(this HtmlHelper htmlHelper, 
                                  string imgName, string alt, int height)
{
    if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(imgName)) imgName = "nopic.jpg";
    var src = String.Format("/Content/ProductImages/{0}", imgName);

    var tagBuilder = new TagBuilder("img");
    tagBuilder.Attributes.Add("src", htmlHelper.Encode(src));
    tagBuilder.Attributes.Add("alt", htmlHelper.Encode(alt));
    tagBuilder.Attributes.Add("height", htmlHelper.Encode(height));

    return MvcHtmlString.Create(tagBuilder.ToString(TagRenderMode.SelfClosing));
}
```

Comment: You could store in your web.config file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I thing  hard coding in programming is bad think because maintenance is so hard you can add key in [web config](http://odetocode.com/articles/345.aspx) and get it easy and if need too change it you can change it easy without publish again
In web config:

```
<add key="ImagePath" value="/Content/ProductImages/"/>
```

In c# code:

```
var path= WebConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ImagePath"].ToString()
```